# I'm new to Maven and is there a better way to search for archetype?

Tags: java, maven-3, java-ee-7

I'm trying to build a project from scratch and I want to build a project from scratch, is there a way to generate archetype without scrolling through CLI? I mean can I specify requirements as a Spring Boot project?

Comment: You know https://start.spring.io/ ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new project , select the maven project in eclipse, it will provide the options for all arch types along with the group I'd and artefact I'd. It will provide the list of all arch types.